# MobaXterm deactivate or change SPACE+altgr shortcut (search macro)

Tags: mobaxterm

Everytime I try to write a pipe " | " in the MobaXterm terminal, I accidentally press SPACE and then the pipe combination (swiss layout altgr+7) at the same time. because SPACE+altgr seems to be the "search macro" search field, this annoying search bar opens every time.

Can this be disabled or changed?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts and change the shortcut for "Execute a macro"